# Generics constraint with nullable types

Tags: c#, .net

I've got these very clearly defined methods that internally all call `InternalGreaterThan()` but can't find a way - without removing the `T` constraint - of making this work for `long?` and `DataTime?`

```
#nullable enable
public static bool GreaterThan(long? @this, long? value)
{
    return InternalGreaterThan(@this, value);
}

public static bool GreaterThan(DateTime? @this, DateTime? value)
{
    return InternalGreaterThan(@this, value);
}

public static bool GreaterThan(Version? @this, Version? value)
{
    return InternalGreaterThan(@this, value);
}

private static bool InternalGreaterThan<T>(T @this, T value) where T : IComparable<T>?
{
    return @this != null && value != null && Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(@this, value) > 0;
}
```

What are my options here without having to remove the `T` constraint (although altering the constraint is of course fine).

Answer (score 1):

You need two separate overloads. One for `T` and one for `T?`. E.g.:

```
private static bool InternalGreaterThan<T>(T @this, T value) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    return Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(@this, value) > 0;
}

private static bool InternalGreaterThan<T>(T? @this, T? value) where T : struct, IComparable<T>
{
    return @this.HasValue && value.HasValue && InternalGreaterThan(@this.Value, value.Value);
}
```

Comment: That works, but you still need the check for `null` in the first overload - `Version` is a nullable type and not a struct...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. Assuming, you can. Than it is possible to make a call like this:

```
DateTime? dt = null;
var result = dt.GreaterThan(null);
```

The system is unable to detect the argument's type. Which version of the method the system should take?

Comment: In this particular case that's not an issue because I always call it via reflection so I know what my data type is and I invoke the correct method from the start. The problem is that when calling via reflection if one of your arguments is `null` and the argument type is non-nullable the system would pass `default()` for the argument type it's trying to match. But I can't assume that if I have a `long`/`DateTime` with value `default()` that it's because the `MethodInfo.Invoke()` cast it to `default()`, as the caller may have actually intended to pass `default()`.

Comment: In the case of `GreaterThan` it's pretty simple as it will automatically return false if one or both arguments are `default()` for any given data type. But what about `Equals`, `LowerThan`, `GreaterOrEquals`, etc? That's why I need to support `null` as a given value (and immediately return `false` if either argument is `null`